# Powershell code to remove matching text giving errors

Tags: powershell, batch-file, replace

I have this code:

```
powershell -Command "(Get-Content C:\users\Public\ITCMD\Toggler\settings.ini) | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch "\b!Friend!\b"} | Set-Content C:\users\Public\ITCMD\Toggler\settings.ini"
```

I set !Friend! to a text value. The script is spitting out these errors:

```
At line:1 char:86
+ ... blic\ITCMD\Toggler\settings.ini) | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch \buhgft ...
+                                                                  ~
You must provide a value expression following the '-notmatch' operator.
At line:1 char:87
+ ... \Toggler\settings.ini) | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch \buhgft\b} | Set- ...
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '\buhgft\b' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

[image: Errors]

Was wondering why it is doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your double-quotes are being interpreted by cmd as the end of your command and causing parsing issues for powershell.  If you replace them with single-quotes, it'll fix the parsing issue:

```
powershell -Command "(Get-Content C:\users\Public\ITCMD\Toggler\settings.ini) |^
    Where-Object {$_ -notmatch '\b!Friend!\b'} |^
    Set-Content C:\users\Public\ITCMD\Toggler\settings.ini"
```